# Create a Publisher for a UIButton

Tags: swift, uikit, combine

I'm using Combine and UIKit, and I want UIButton to be publisher.

Is there any way to achieve this like RxSwift does?

```swift
button.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext: { weak self } _ in )
```

Comment: Hopefully [this](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/building-custom-combine-publishers-in-swift/) comprehensive guide by Sundell should help you

Comment: There is nothing built in. I give complete instructions for my own solution here: https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/publishers/publisherscustom.html

Comment: And https://github.com/mattneub/CheckWeather/blob/master/CheckWeather/UtilityViews/UIControl%2BPublisher.swift

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing built in.

The simple solution is to make a button subclass where the button is its own target and it signals through a `@Published` property that others can subscribe to.

The more sophisticated way is to write your own generalized UIControl publisher. Here's what I use:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

protocol ControlWithPublisher : UIControl {}
extension UIControl : ControlWithPublisher {}
extension ControlWithPublisher {
    func publisher(for event: UIControl.Event = .primaryActionTriggered) -> ControlPublisher<Self> {
        ControlPublisher(control:self, for:event)
    }
}

struct ControlPublisher<T:UIControl> : Publisher {
    typealias Output = T
    typealias Failure = Never
    unowned let control : T
    let event : UIControl.Event
    init(control:T, for event:UIControl.Event = .primaryActionTriggered) {
        self.control = control
        self.event = event
    }
    func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, S.Input == Output, S.Failure == Failure {
        subscriber.receive(subscription: Inner(downstream: subscriber, sender: control, event: event))
    }
    class Inner <S:Subscriber>: NSObject, Subscription where S.Input == Output, S.Failure == Failure {
        weak var sender : T?
        let event : UIControl.Event
        var downstream : S?
        init(downstream: S, sender : T, event : UIControl.Event) {
            self.downstream = downstream
            self.sender = sender
            self.event = event
            super.init()
        }
        func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) {
            self.sender?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doAction), for: event)
        }
        @objc func doAction(_ sender:UIControl) {
            guard let sender = self.sender else {return}
            _ = self.downstream?.receive(sender)
        }
        private func finish() {
            self.sender?.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(doAction), for: event)
            self.sender = nil
            self.downstream = nil
        }
        func cancel() {
            self.finish()
        }
        deinit {
            self.finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why having that protocol constrained to `UIControl`? Why not simply adding the extension over `UIControl`? Also, regarding the demand semantics, your publisher doesn't seem to respect those, as there is no check over the demand.

Comment: Yeah, it's deliberately simplified, just enough to let me get work done. Feel free to write a better version!

Answer (score 3):

@matt already gave an excellent solution, adding my own solution just to have a publisher that handles the demand in the appropriate manner.

This is how I'd implement such a publisher:

```
extension UIControl {
    func publisher(forEvent event: Event = .primaryActionTriggered) -> Publishers.Control {
        .init(control: self, event: event)
    }
}

extension Publishers {
    struct Control: Publisher {
        typealias Output = Void
        typealias Failure = Never
        
        private let control: UIControl
        private let event: UIControl.Event
        
        init(control: UIControl, event: UIControl.Event) {
            self.control = control
            self.event = event
        }
        
        func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Never == S.Failure, Void == S.Input {
            subscriber.receive(subscription: Subscription(subscriber, control, event))
        }
        
        private class Subscription<S>: NSObject, Combine.Subscription where S: Subscriber, S.Input == Void, S.Failure == Never {
            private var subscriber: S?
            private weak var control: UIControl?
            private let event: UIControl.Event
            private var unconsumedDemand = Subscribers.Demand.none
            private var unconsumedEvents = 0
            
            init(_ subscriber: S, _ control: UIControl, _ event: UIControl.Event) {
                self.subscriber = subscriber
                self.control = control
                self.event = event
                super.init()
                
                control.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onEvent), for: event)
            }
            
            deinit {
                control?.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(onEvent), for: event)
            }
                        
            func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) {
                unconsumedDemand += demand
                consumeDemand()
            }
            
            func cancel() {
                subscriber = nil
            }
            
            private func consumeDemand() {
                while let subscriber = subscriber, unconsumedDemand > 0, unconsumedEvents > 0 {
                    unconsumedDemand -= 1
                    unconsumedEvents -= 1
                    unconsumedDemand += subscriber.receive(())
                }
            }

            private func onEvent() {
                unconsumedEvents += 1
                consumeDemand()
            }
        }
    }
}
```